# Serialising XML from database with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, servicestack

An application I'm working with has a number of user-defined screens and fields which are stored in a SQL database as XML.

I am using ServiceStack to build a web API for use in the application.  One of the things I will need to do is to take the user-defined data from XML and pass it out via ServiceStack.  I am a little concerned about the cost in querying from the database, serialising from XML into C# object (service) and then ServiceStack serialising once more into JSON or whatever format is requested.  I've thought about storing as JSON blob instead of XML but I need to also be able to query the data purely from within the SQL realm.

I have a couple of questions:
Has anyone got any recommendations on minimising the cost of serialisation?

Does ServiceStack have any built in functionality that may assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Serializers are particularly hard to deserialize into POCO's it doesn't know about and may require extra hints on the destination model attributed with either `[DataContract]` or [XmlSerializer Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) depending on which .NET XML serializer you choose. ServiceStack has wrappers around both of these serializers which implement the `IStringSerializable` interface:

```
var dto = DataContractSerializer.Instance.Parse<T>(xml)
var dto = XmlSerializableSerializer.Instance.Parse<T>(xml)
```

However as they're XML Serializers are fairly strict and fragile I'll tend to go with the built-in [XLinq Extension methods](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/XLinqExtensions.cs) which makes it easy to traverse an XML document and pluck out the values you want as seen in the 
[XlinqExtensionsTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/Xlinq/XlinqExtensionsTests.cs)